# Python: Convert a text file multi-level JSON

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script in `python` to go recursively through each file, create a JSON object from the file that looks like this:

```
target_id   length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000619216.1   68  33.8839 2.83333 4.64528
ENST00000473358.1   712 428.88  0   0
ENST00000469289.1   535 306.32  0   0
ENST00000607096.1   138 69.943  0   0
ENST00000417324.1   1187    844.464 0   0
ENST00000461467.1   590 342.551 3.44007 0.557892
ENST00000335137.3   918 588.421 0   0
ENST00000466430.5   2748    2405.46 75.1098 1.73463
ENST00000495576.1   1319    976.464 11.1999 0.637186
```

This is my script:

```
import glob
import os
import json

# define datasets
# Dataset name
datasets = ['pnoc']

# open file in append mode
f = open('mydict','a')

# define a new object
data={}

# traverse through folders of datasets
for d in datasets:
    samples = glob.glob(d + "/data"  + "/*.tsv")
    for s in samples:
        # get the SampleName without extension and path
        fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s))[0]

        # split the basename to get sample name and norm method
        sname, keyword, norm = fname.partition('.')

        # determing Normalization method based on filename
        if norm == "abundance":
            norm = "kallisto"
        elif norm == "rsem_genes.results":
            norm = "rsem_genes"
        else:
            norm = "rsem_isoforms"

        # read each file
        with open(s) as samp:
            next(samp)
            for line in samp:
                sp = line.split('\t')
                data.setdefault(sname,[]).append({"ID": sp[0],"Expression": sp[4]})
                json.dump(data, f)
f.close()
```

I want a JSON object on the following lines:

```
# 20000 Sample names, 3 Normalization methods and 60000 IDs in each file.
DatasetName1 {
    SampleName1 {
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }   
    },
    SampleName2 {
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }   
    },
    ...
    SampleName20000{
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is - When converting a text file to JSON, how do I set the levels in my JSON output?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you condense this down to an MCVE? I don't think there's any reason to include so much information in your question about what you're working with and how you've named your files and such. Produce a very simple example of half a dozen lines showing what you want to do.

Comment: Any special reason to use 8 space indentation?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I have updated my question.

Comment: @chapelo No special reason. It was just my vi editor that indented it out to 8 spaces.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON...

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of setting the default value over and over, you should make use of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Secondly, I think your proposed structure is off, and you should be using some arrays within (JSON-like structure):

```
{
    DatasetName1: {
        SampleName1: {
            Type: {
                Normalization1: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization2: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization3: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ]
            }
        },
        SampleName2: {
            Type: {
                Normalization1: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization2: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization3: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ]
            }
        },
        ...
        SampleName20000: {
            Type: {
                Normalization1: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization2: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ],
                Normalization3: [
                    { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                    { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                    ...
                    { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
    DatasetName2: {
        ...
    }, ...
}
```

So your resulting code (untested) should look like this (long as your norm method logic is correct):

```
from glob import glob
from os import path
from json import dump
from collections import defaultdict

# define datasets, and result dict
datasets, results = ['pnoc'], defaultdict(dict)

# open file in append mode
with open('mydict','a') as f:
    # traverse through folders of datasets
    for d in datasets:
        for s in glob(d + "/data"  + "/*.tsv"):
            sample = {"Type": defaultdict(list)}

            # get the basename without extension and path
            fname = path.splitext(path.basename(s))[0]

            # split the basename to get sample name and norm method
            sname, keyword, norm = fname.partition('.')

            # determing norm method based on filename
            if norm == "abundance":
                norm = "kallisto"
            elif norm == "rsem_genes.results":
                norm = "rsem_genes"
            else:
                norm = "rsem_isoforms"

            # read each file
            with open(s) as samp:
                next(samp)              # Skip first line of file

                # Loop through each line and extract the ID and TPM
                for (id, _, __, ___, tpm) in (line.split('\t') for line in samp):
                    # Add this line to the list for respective normalization method
                    sample['Type'][norm].append({"ID": id, "Expression": float(tpm)})
            # Add sample to dataset
            results[d][sname] = sample
    dump(results, f)
```

This will save the result in a JSON format.

Comment: I have posted the first few lines of my file. I don't understand what are the dashes in `id,_,__,___, tpm` doing? I am getting this error. ```for (id, _, __, ___, tpm) in (line.split('\t') for line in samp):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file```

Comment: What is `sample = {"Type": defaultdict(list)} ` doing?

Comment: @KomalRathi The dashes are just variable names used to indicate variables that aren't used. Feel free to add names to them if you plan to use it. You are getting that error because that `for` loop is not indented under your `with` statement. For your second comment, `sample` is set to a `dict` with a single key named **Type** and the value for that key is a `dict` where its values will be a `list` when accessed by *any key*. This is where [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) shines.

Comment: It's a bit odd to use different `_` names as if anybody could distinguish them anyway. Usually it's just `_` for each unused value.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would cause a conflict/issues in reusing `_` in the same tuple declaration. I guess one way to find out!